I dont understand how to solve this Boolean Algebra question Help
Let S be a set and let F UN(S, {0, 1}) be the set of all functions with domain S
and codomain {0, 1}. Define the Boolean operations on F UN(S, {0, 1}) as follows:
Let F, G ∈ F UN(S, {0, 1}), then
(a) F + G : S → {0, 1} is the function defined by (F + G)(x) = F(x) + G(x) for
all x ∈ S,
(b) F · G : S → {0, 1} is the function defined by (F · G)(x) = F(x) · G(x) for all
x ∈ S,
(c) F barenter image description here : S → {0, 1} is the function defined by F(x) = F(x) for all x ∈ S,
Find that F UN(S, {0, 1}) together with these operations is a Boolean Algebra.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Tell us what have you tried
